# How to create user who can grant anything in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want a dedicated limited user in MySQL which is used to create a new database, create a new user and grant all permissions for that new db to the new user. According to [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html), to grant anything to anyone, you need `Alternatively, if you have the UPDATE privilege for the grant tables in the mysql system database, you can grant any account any privilege.`.

These are the priviledges I tried:

```
GRANT CREATE, CREATE ROLE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE USER, DROP ROLE, RELOAD, SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO `admin-xxx`@`46.x.x.x` WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON `mysql`.* TO `admin-xxx`@`46.x.x.x`;
```

I can create the database and user, but GRANT fails with:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'admin-xxx'@'46.x.x.x' to database 'xxx_abc'
```

What else is needed according to the manual to be able to GRANT the privileges?

**EDIT:**

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin-xxx@46.x.x.x                                                                                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT CREATE, RELOAD, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE USER, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `admin-xxx`@`46.x.x.x` WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON `mysql`.* TO `admin-xxx`@`46.x.x.x`                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What does `show grants for 'admin-xxx'@'46.x.x.x';` outputs ? Which user are you using for giving permissions , please show grants for that user ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha added. It shows correctly. It seems I don't fully understand the manual on what exactly is needed to be able to grant anything to anyone without being superuser.

Answer (score 0):

You have add after grant

```
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: According to manual this is not needed when using the GRANT command. Needed only when directly modifying the grant tables, which is deprecated. Also verified by using `SHOW GRANTS` when connected as that user.